# how do I make webpack not convert process.env variables to their values during build?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I have the following in one of my project files:

```
const baas = process.env.DBID;
console.log('baas', baas);
```

If I run:

```
cross-env PORT=4000 NODE_ENV=production WEBPACK_CONFIG=browser_prod,server_prod webpack --colors
```

My server.js file looks like:

```
const baas = undefined;
console.log('baas', baas);
```

As expected. However, I want to be able to set the ID when I run the built app not when I build the app, ie:

```
DBID=someotherid node dist/server.js
```

So I need webpack to not convert `const baas = process.env.DBID` to it's value at build time, but rather leave it as is, so the `server.js` uses it's value at runtime.

How do I do this?

Note: if I manually edit the built `server.js` and change `undefined` to `process.env.DBID` then the run script works and the app uses the env var from run time, but I don't want to edit files after building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is `process.argv` not `process.env`:

```
// server.js

const baas = process.argv[0];
console.log('baas', baas);
```

Then:

```
node dist/server.js baas_value
```

For convenience, you can use this module https://www.npmjs.com/package/yargs

Answer (score 2):

You are using the wrong target.
By default, webpack builds the application to be run in the browser. This means it will mock native node functions like `path` `fs` and `process`

Your target is node, so there is no need to mock these.
Add this to your `webpack.config.js`

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'node'
};
```

https://webpack.js.org/concepts/targets/#usage

Answer (score 0):

I was able to prevent Webpack from converting `process.env` by accessing it indirectly like this:

```
const processText = "process";
const _process = global[processText];
app.listen(_process.env.PORT || 2000);
```

You need to get `process` indirectly instead of `env` because the `process` variable is defined by webpack to be something like `/* provided dependency */ var process = __webpack_require__(/*! process/browser */ "process/browser");`